# xml values are not inserting into the table

Tags: sql-server, xml

Here is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_Insertxmldata
    @xml xml
AS
BEGIN
    declare @hdoc as int

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc output,@xml 

    Insert into tbllogin([user_name],mobile,[Password])
    select [USER_NAME],mobile,[password] 
    FROM openxml(@hdoc, '/NewDataSet/table', 2) 
    with 
    (
        [user_name] varchar(50)'@username',
        mobile varchar(50) '@mobile',
        [password] varchar(15) '@password'
    )

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc  

END
GO
```

The xml is:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <user_name></user_name>
    <password></password>
    <mobile></mobile>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: You must add details about your problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no error message or other clue. Take the tour and check out the "help us to help you" blog (both at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using the XML datatype, you must be using SQL Server 2005 or above. Therefore you can use the methods of the XML datatype (eg `.nodes`, `.value`, `.query`) to read the XML. For such a small piece of XML performance is likely to be the same or better than OPENXML, eg

```
DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml = '<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <user_name></user_name>
    <password></password>
    <mobile></mobile>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>'

--INSERT INTO ...
SELECT
    t.c.value('(user_name/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)' ),
    t.c.value('(mobile/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)' ),
    t.c.value('(password/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(15)' )
FROM @xml.nodes('NewDataSet/Table1') t(c)
```

Remember when dealing with XML, things are generally case-sensitive, so I'm using 'Table1' rather than 'table' as per your original post.